# ES6 Destructuring and Module imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, es6-modules

I was under the impression that this syntax:

```
import Router from 'react-router';
var {Link} = Router;
```

has the same final result as this:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';
```

Can someone explain what the difference is?

(I originally thought it was a [React Router Bug](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2468).)

Comment: Unfortunately they have the same shorthand syntax, but if you check their long forms they are clearly different: `var {"Link": Link} = Router;` vs `import {Link as Link} from '…';`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';
```

imports a **named export** from `react-router`, i.e. something like

```
export const Link = 42;
```

---

```
import Router from 'react-router';
const {Link} = Router;
```

pulls out the property `Link` from the **default export**, assuming it is an object, e.g.

```
export default {
  Link: 42
};
```

(the default export is actually nothing but a standardized named export with the name "default").

See also [`export` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Complete example:

```
// react-router.js
export const Link = 42;
export default {
  Link: 21,
};


// something.js
import {Link} from './react-router';
import Router from './react-router';
const {Link: Link2} = Router;

console.log(Link); // 42
console.log(Link2); // 21
```

---

With Babel 5 and below I believe they have been interchangeable because of the way ES6 modules have been transpiled to CommonJS. But those are two different constructs as far as the language goes.

Comment: Great answer. The syntax to import a named export is very easily confused for the deconstructing syntax of an object.

Comment: Babel 6 does *not* make the two interchangable. Beware!

Answer (score 15):

To do this:

```
import {purple, grey} from 'themeColors';
```

*Without repeating `export const` for each symbol*, just do:

```
export const
  purple = '#BADA55',
  grey = '#l0l',
  gray = grey,
  default = 'this line actually causes an error';
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for different exports, it may also lead to
different bundled code by WebPack when using two variant ways to destruct ESM modules:

```js
// react-router
export function Link(str) { /* ... */ }
```

1. Destruct within the `import` statement:

   ```js
   import {Link} from 'react-router';

   Link('1');
   Link('2');
   ```

   ```js
   // WebPack output
   var util_mobileValidator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(1);
   (0,util_mobileValidator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Link)('1');
   (0,util_mobileValidator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Link)('2');
   ```
2. Use destructuring syntax:

   ```js
   import * as Router from 'react-router';
   const {Link} = Router;

   Link('1');
   Link('2');
   ```

   ```js
   // WebPack output:
   var util_mobileValidator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(1);
   const {Link} = util_mobileValidator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__;
   Link(1);
   Link(2);
   ```

As you can see in the output example above where there is redundant code, which is not good for optimization when trying to uglify via `UglifyJS`, or `Terser`.