# what is the difference between using import { a } from 'somewhere' and import a from 'somewhere' in ES6?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between using

```
import { Devices } from '../models/devices';
```

and

```
import Devices from '../models/devices';
```

I haven't been able to google this one out yet.

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports/33524809

Answer (score 2):

I believe the first is a `Named-Import` and the second is a `Default-Binding`.

In simple English, I think the first one means "from all the stuff that was exported in `../models/devices`, import only the `Devices` object". While the second one means "whatever is the default export of `../models/devices`, import it as the name `Devices`.

See [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports). I must admit, though, I'm not 100% my interpretation is correct. That document was not written for mere humans to read, it seems... :/