# $q and promises' status

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Consider the following code:

```
var qq=$q(function(resolve, reject) {   
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (true) {
            console.log(qq);
            resolve('Hello!');
            console.log(qq);
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }, 5000);
});

console.log(qq);
```

There are three `console.log` commands. The last one is executed first and it correctly outputs a promise object with status 0.  I was waiting for the first `console.log` inside `setTimeout` to output a promise object with pending status (0), since it stands before resolve. However, both of `console.log` commands inside `setTimeout` output a resolved promise with status 1. Could someone explain that to me?

Comment: Console in browser always displays the current object state. Log it with JSON.stringify or log the promise status directly instead of the object

Comment: Yup.  The browser logs a reference to the object, but it can't write to the log until the script has yielded the CPU.  The script ends (or yields the CPU some other way), and the log entries are resolved.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, please?

Comment: Have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/q/33524696/1048572](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/1048572), altough what you describe is a bit weirder.

Comment: @Amy "*it can't write to the log until the script has yielded the CPU*" assumes single-threaded execution, for which there is no reason. The console likely lives in its own process.

Comment: Don't forget that the JavaScript interpreter is single-threaded.