# Named export vs exporting an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why does this work:

```
const str = 'stuff';
export {
  str
};
```

But not this:

```
export default {
  str: 'stuff'
};
```

I'd like to import it as the following:

```
import { str } from 'myLib';
```

I'd like to assign the value directly in the export and not require having to create a variable before hand.

Also when I try:

```
export {
  str: 'stuff'
};
```

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: /home/karlm/dev/project/ex.js: Unexpected token, expected , (41:5)
  39 | 
  40 | export {
> 41 |   str: 'stuff'
     |      ^
  42 | };
  43 |
```

Comment: That is just how the export syntax works. It *looks* like object destructuring, which I guess is why you have expected to be able to export an *object*, but the two concepts are fundamentally different. Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports

Comment: Kind of related: [ES6 Destructuring and Module imports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33524696/218196)

Comment: Also related: [Javascript (ES6), export const vs export default](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33611812/218196)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two styles of exports in ES6 -- *named* exports, and the *default* export. Named exports get exported with syntax like this:

```
export const str = 'stuff';
// or
const str = 'stuff';
export { str };
```

Default exports go like this:

```
const obj = { str: 'stuff' };
export default obj;
// or 
export default {
  str: 'stuff'
};
```

The difference shows up when you import. With the first, you need to include braces:

```
import { str } from 'myModule'; // 'stuff', from the first example
```

Without braces, it imports the default export:

```
import myModule from 'myModule'; //  {str: 'stuff'}, from the second example
```

Comment: Updated my question regarding your first part, I get an error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Edited.

Comment: Actually you can't default export a variable declaration. `export default const str = 'stuff';` is invalid.

Comment: It's all wrong. There are no _normal_ exports. Both types are normal. It's either *default* export or *named* export. Besides, as @Qwerty noticed - you can't default-export a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason of the [export statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) is to be used to export functions, objects or primitives from a given file (or module).

But you need an identifier in order to be exported (so that it can be imported via `import` in another script).

You can simply do:

```
export const obj = {
  str: 'stuff'
};
```

During the [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), you will be able to use the same name `obj` to refer to the corresponding value.

And import it like:

```
import { obj } from 'myLib';
```