# Spread an object before exporting

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I've got an object that's generated basing on another object. The object's type is fully known. It looks like this.

```
const mediaHooks = {
   sm: () => {}, //some func
   md: () => {}, //some func
};
```

Now, I would like to 'spread' that object before exporting, so its properties count as a top-level export and I can import them like:

```
import {sm} from './media';
```

Is it possible?

Comment: @Terry default exporting an object isn't the same thing as named exporting all of its properties separately, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41283733/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not technically possible.

Instead, consider flipping your approach by using named exports and namespace imports

```
// media-hooks.js
export const sm = () => {}; //some func
export const md = () => {}; //some func

// app.js
import * as mediaHooks from './media-hooks' ;
import {sm} from './media-hooks';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [export assignments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) for a commonJs/AMD like export to get the wished behavior. But this removes the ability to export anything else in that file:

```
export = mediaHooks;
// can be imported now as import {sm} from './media'; in another file
```

Everything else you want to export from that file also needs to be contained in the `mediaHooks` object. If that's not feasible for you, there is no way to spread an object in an export. In that case maybe something like this would be a good enough alternative:

```
export const {sm, md} = mediaHooks;
```