# import variable in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

i am storing values into three different variable.

```
const companyValue = useSelector((state) => state.changeCompanyReducer.company);
const selectionValueArray = Object.values(companyValue);
const companyCode = selectionValueArray[0];
const employeeId = selectionValueArray[1];
```

i am getting 3 values from **selectionValueArray** , **companyCode**  , **employeeId** .

i want to place whole code in one file and import all these three variable name anywhere i want so that i can get 3 different values.

How can i achieve this?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
export const companyValue = your value
export const selectionValueArray = some value
```

Now you have to import like

```
import {companyValue, selectionValueArray} from './yourfile'
```

This type of import and export is called named export and import.

Learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283733/named-export-vs-exporting-an-object/41283945)