# What does the brackets means around the param list inside an arrow function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

[image]

This is a simple ES6 arrow function, but I can't find the benefits of wraping the *( **onClick, completed, text** )* params with brackets ( aka : *(**{** onClick, completed, text **}**)* ) - no doc mention - no examples

```
const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => ( <---- here
  <li
    onClick={onClick}
    style={{
      textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </li>
)

export default Todo
```

I guess this looks like when we do import :

```
import  { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
```

Cheers

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol : Good link, but it's hard to find something you actually don't know ( "Object Destructuring" ). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

You are looking at a react code, in which props is an object:

```
const props = { onClick: function() {}, completed: false, text: 'some string' };
```

To use the `props` object properties directly, we use destructuring to assign them to separate variables:

```
const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => ( <---- here
  <li
    onClick={onClick} // <-- the onClick variable
    style={{
      textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'  // <-- the completed variable
    }}
  >
    {text}  // <-- the text variable
  </li>
)
```

If we didn't use destructuring, we'll have to get the properties from the `props` object using the dot notation:

```
const Todo = (props) => ( <---- here
  <li
    onClick={props.onClick} // <-- the onClick property
    style={{
      textDecoration: props.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'  // <-- the completed property
    }}
  >
    {props.text}  // <-- the text property
  </li>
)
```

Destructuring and Import have a very close syntax, but their not the doing exactly the same thing - you can read more about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33524809/5157454).