# object destructuring in react-create-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, create-react-app

In a file called index.js i have the following export:

```
export default {
  foo: true,
  bar: false
}
```

Later in file home.js i'm doing the following:

```
import { foo, bar } from './index'

console.log(foo, bar) -> undefined, undefined
```

If i import everything like:

```
import index from './index'

console.log(index) -> { foo: true, bar: false }
```

Can someone explain me why this is happening? I'm doing something wrong?

I'm using:

> › create-react-app -V
>   1.0.3

Comment: this is how it should work as specified in ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Related: [ES6 Destructuring and Module imports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33524696/218196), [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36795819/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there are [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_named_exports), not destructuring.

You have to export them as such, not as a [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export):

```
// this will export all of the defined properties as individual
// named exports, which you can pick-and-choose when importing
// using a similar syntax to destructuring
const foo = true, bar = false;
export {
  foo,
  bar
}

// imported exports named 'foo' and 'bar'
import { foo, bar } from './my-file'.
```

If you specify a `default` export, then whatever follows the keyword `default` will be exported when you import without curly braces:

```
// this exports an object containing { foo, bar } as the default export
export default {
  foo: true,
  bar: false
}

// imported without {}
import objectContainingFooBar from './my-file';
```