# How do I use destructing with importing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, import, export

I have the following:

**SomeDirectory/index.js**

```
import Foo from './foo';
import Bar from './bar';
import Baz from './baz';

export default {
  Foo,
  Bar,
  Baz,
};
```

And in my file, I want to just import like this:

**SomeFile.js**

```
import { Foo, Bar, Baz } from './SomeDirectory'
```

And then be able to use `Foo`, `Bar`, or `Baz` as is but instead I have to do:

```
import Container from './SomeDirectory'
```

and use it with `Container.Foo`

Comment: Just remove default in the index.js file and it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Destructuring and Module imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports)