# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token { in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phaser-framework

I'm getting started to Phaser 3, and I was trying to make the initial "game scenes", and I tried to use the :

```
import { blah } from "../asdf/blah";
```

ES6 syntax, and I get this error:

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token {

I'm not really sure why this happens, my browser supports that statement! ( Chrome 71 )

The parts of the code that implement "import" :

```
/* main.js */

import { loadScene } from "./scenes/loadScene";
import { menuScene } from "./scenes/menuScene";

let game = new Phaser.Game({
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    scene: [
        loadScene, menuScene
    ]
});

//------------------End of main.js--------------------

/* loadScene.js */

import { CST } from "../CST";

export class loadScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({
            key: CST.SCENES.LOAD
        });
    }

    create() {
        this.scene.start(CST.SCENES.MENU, "Hello from loadScene");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a bundler like webpack or parcel? If not, how are you loading the code into the browser?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports

Comment: Seems like you are not loading the code as module in the browser.

Comment: @DerekNguyen yes, I'm using parcel to do that.

Comment: @FelixKling I've heard that you can load it as a module by modifying the <script> tag, so, "import" just works with JS loaded as a Module? Thank you.