# Is `import { useState } from 'react'` kind of destructure or not?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, destructuring

I'd like to make clear one thing.

In React, we often use `import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'`.

Can we think of this as a destructuring feature in ES6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 Destructuring and Module imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at react [src code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/index.js#L39-L88)

```js
export {
  useState,
  // ...
  Children,
  // ....
} from './src/React';
```

so you can import directly from this object e.g.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
// you can also rename it to anything you want
import { useState as useReactState } from 'react'
```

or you can get the whole object as exported as default and then reference its `useState`

```
import React from 'react'

// use React.useState
// renaming will be like assigning a function to another variable e.g.
const useReactState = React.useState

// you also get all exported types and modules and wrap them up in React name 
import * as React from 'react'
```

**Babel transpiled outputs**

```
import React from 'react'
const Component = () => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState()
}
// will transpile to something like
var Component = function Component() {
  var _React$useState = _react["default"].useState(),
      _React$useState2 = _slicedToArray(_React$useState, 2),
      state = _React$useState2[0],
      setState = _React$useState2[1];
};
```

On the other hand

```
import {useState} from 'react'
const Component = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState()
}
// will transpile to something like
var Component = function Component() {
  var _useState = (0, _react.useState)(),
      _useState2 = _slicedToArray(_useState, 2),
      state = _useState2[0],
      setState = _useState2[1];
};
```

There are some similarities between object destruction and import/export statement, but they are not the same at the end both have their own specific features different with the other

[ES6 in-depth](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/) |
[Export Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) |
[Import Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 1):

Nope.
It's not like object destructuring but it is actually importing named exports.
To be more clear, it's just importing a module exported as `useState`.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different.

While they look similar (and probably `import` was *designed to look like destructuring*), they don't behave the same way. To set that clear, `import`ing uses a slightly different syntax: uses the `as` keyword for import renaming instead of the `:` familiar from destructuring.

These differences are because of how the module system works. Other differences are:

- `import`ed variables cannot be assigned to by the importer module, however...
- the `export`ed variables can be changed anytime by the exporter, and that will also be reflected by the importers' variables, and that implies, that...
- it's not possible to nest import renaming, like how it would be possible via destructuring:

  ```
  import {foo as {bar as baz}} from './module'; 
  //is invalid, as is:
  import {foo as {bar: baz}} from './module'; 
  //...while:

  const {foo: {bar: baz}} = value; 
  //is valid.
  ```
- as the module system is static (like variables), it's not possible to import a dynamic key or use the rest syntax (all imports are known *before* evaluating the code).