# How to create a npm package with multiple vue directives? Or should I create one package per directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, npm-publish, vue-directives

I am able to create an npm package by exporting a single vue directive in the src/index.js file. But how can I create a package that lets you use multiple vue directives. I am not able to export two vue directives in the same index.js file.

```
export default Vue.directive('directive1', {
  inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => mouseup(e, el, _data))
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => mousedown(e, el, _data))
    el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousemove(e, el, _data))
    setDraggerOffset(el, _data)
  }
})

export default Vue.directive('directive2', {
  inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => mouseup(e, el, _data))
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => mousedown(e, el, _data))
    el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousemove(e, el, _data))
    setDraggerOffset(el, _data)
  }
})
```

Comment: why not export one `install` function, then the users can use `Vue.use` to install your directive into their Vue app.

Comment: please can you elaborate? This is the first time I am doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to export two defaults. A default means you can get the value by just saying `import MyPack from 'path/to/package'`. You need to export constants, and destructure where you are importing. [Learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports)

In the package

```js
export const vD1 = Vue.directive('directive1', {
  ...
})

export const vD2 = Vue.directive('directive2', {
  ...
})
```

Wherever you're importing:

```js
import { vD1, vD2 } from 'path/to/package';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Vue Guide: Writing one plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin), we can follow this guide to develop our directives, then allow the users to activate specific directives by 2nd parameters=`options`.

Like below demo (assuming export `myDirectives`, and only enable `directive1`):

```js
let myDirectives = {}
let _defaultDirectives = ['directive1', 'directive2']
myDirectives.directive1 = {
  inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => mouseup(e, el, _data))
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => mousedown(e, el, _data))
    el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousemove(e, el, _data))
    console.log('directive1', `setDraggerOffset(el, _data)`)
  }
}

myDirectives.directive2 = {
  inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => mouseup(e, el, _data))
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => mousedown(e, el, _data))
    el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousemove(e, el, _data))
    console.log('directive2', `setDraggerOffset(el, _data)`)
  }
}

myDirectives.install = function (Vue, options) {
  let selectedDirectives = (options && options.directives) || _defaultDirectives
  selectedDirectives.forEach((directive) => 
    Vue.directive(directive, this[directive])
    // this[directive + 'Definition'] = Vue.directive(directive, this[directive])
  )
}

// export default myDirectives

// Vue.use(myDirectives) // default option is register both directive1 and directive 2
Vue.use(myDirectives, {directives: ['directive1'] }) // register directive1 only

// console.log('Definition', myDirectives.directive1Definition, myDirectives.directive2Definition)

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-directive1></span>
  <span v-directive2></span>
</div>
```